# Ionic 2 running ionic cordova run android command issue

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, android-sdk-tools

I am getting the below error when I run the command `ionic cordova run android` for running the app on devide...

```
> cordova run android
[11:19:06]  lint finished in 3.93 s 
ANDROID_HOME=/root/android-sdks
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

FAILURE: Could not determine which tasks to execute.

* What went wrong:
Task 'wrapper' not found in root project 'android'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.93 secs
Error: /usr/share/gradle/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1).
```

Please help me to get resolve this one. Thank you in advance.

Below are the output of info :

ionic info

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.0
```

System:

```
Node : v8.4.0
npm  : 5.3.0 
OS   : Linux 3.13
```

Comment: Can you add the out put of `ionic info`, please?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Valentin. I have added the ionic info details into questions itself now. Please check those and let me know what I need to do further.

Comment: I assume you have tried to remove the Android platform and then add it again?

Answer (score 0):

You should try installing the latest gradle version in the same folder as before. You can find it [here](https://gradle.org/releases/).

Comment: I have Gradle 4.1 version and this is latest one.

Answer (score 0):

This issue got solved by installing typing-script \n "`npm install -g tsd`".
And creating new project `ionic cordova run android` works for me on same node 8.4.0 version.